# Create a job to fetch records from table with specific column format and replace with required format

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I need to create a job in X++ to fetch records from table X with column having id's having format ER5000123440
and replace 5 with -0 in ax. The 5 is the number coming immediate after ER.

after replacing the id will be ER-0000123440.

```
Select EXPENSEID 
from ms_it_dms_staging 
where EXPENSEID like 'ER4%'
and ms_it_dms_staging.FAILUREREASON=3
```

this is the code in sql. 
Can u help me write this in x++

Comment: Do you have any code you're starting with? What you're requesting isn't readily possible. Why do you need the columns to be named in that fashion? You need to provide more info. Is table `X` a static table or do you need to dynamically name the columns?

Comment: the values are populating into the table where I am trying to replace those values.

Comment: i am new to ax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have AX in front of me, so there may be syntax errors, but this is basically what you'll do:

```
// Declare variable to hold your new ID temporarily
str myNewId;
// Declare the table buffer variable
ms_it_dms_staging ms_it_dms_staging;

ttsbegin; // Begin a transaction
while select forupdate ms_it_dms_staging 
  where ms_it_dms_staging.EXPENSEID like 'ER5*' &&
        ms_it_dms_staging.FAILUREREASON == 3
{
    // Do your logic here to change the ID. Make sure this works correctly, may need to adjust the start digit.
    // This doesn't need to be in a variable but I'm making it simpler
    myNewId = strfmt("ER-0%1", subStr(ms_it_dms_staging.EXPENSEID, 3, maxInt()));

    ms_it_dms_staging.EXPENSEID = myNewId;
    ms_it_dms_staging.update();
}
ttscommit; // Commit the transaction
```